# makefiles compiling files to library

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm new to makefiles , recently I was looking at a makefile and could not understand what this means

```
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

where 
PROJECT_ROOT=.
EXTERNAL_ROOT=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/external
SRCDIR = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/src
OBJDIR = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/myobjs
BINDIR = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/mybins
DOCDIR = $(PROJECT_ROOT)/doc
```

what does it represent? Also i wish to make static library consistly of all files in in the myobjs folder or $(OBJS) except main.o a file in it how to write the command
ar -cvq mylibs/libCS296test.a $(OBJS); for such a case?

Answer (score 1):

Please create different SO requests for very different questions.

For your first question, that is equivalent to this function:

```
$(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

which basically says "look through the value of the `$(SOURCES)` variable and for every word matching the pattern `$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp`, replace it with the pattern `$(OBJDIR)/%.o`.  So, if `SOURCES` contained a word `./external/src/foo/bar/biz.cpp` that would be replaced with `./external/myobjs/foo/bar/biz.o`.